# Placeholder type label for XtraReport

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm looking for a way to have a label and bound text inside an XtraReport control. Something where I can put a label in the top left corner and bind text from the data source aligned to the middle right. Does such a control exist? Some other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have

> bind text from the data source

I would suggest you first bind the datasource to the band. Once the datasource is bound to the reportband, then just drag and drop an XRLabel (XtraLabel is incorrect) unto the report document. On that label control, use it's smart tag to bind it to a table > field from the datasource.

additional reading

- [Providing Data to Reports](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2594)
- [Create a Data-Aware Report](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2596)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Format as label.text. So you can set variable Text in the label.

```
label.text = string.Format("Hello, {0}", myVariable);
```

So give the variable to the Constructor of the Report and use it to create dynamic lable.

I hope that i understand your question.

regards